# How to post json to Durable Azure Functions (Python)?

Tags: azure-durable-functions

I have working Durable Function based on following tutorial. I have not modified code yet.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode

How to send json file to Activity Function.
For debugging purposes how to do logging.info for json in Activity Function.

## This function an HTTP starter function for Durable Functions.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, None)

    logging.info(f"Started orchestration (Ken) with ID = '{instance_id}'.")

     return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
```

## This function is an Orchestration Function

```
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df


def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):

    logging.info(f"CalcOrc")

    result1 = yield context.call_activity('CalculateActivity', "Tokyo")
    result2 = yield context.call_activity('CalculateActivity', "Seattle")
    result3 = yield context.call_activity('CalculateActivity', "London")
    return [result1, result2, result3]

main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

## This function is an Activity function

```
 import logging

def main(name: str) -> str:
    logging.info(f"CalcAct") # Could log contents of json sent by HTTP Post
    return f"Hello {name}!"
```

## This modified version an HTTP starter function. It works with Get but not with Post.

```
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df


async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> 
func.HttpResponse:

    #Added for testing
    jsoninput = req.params.get('jsoninput')

    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    #instance_id = await 
client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, None)
    instance_id = await 
client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], jsoninput, None)

    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    logging.info(f"jsonInput = '{jsoninput}'.")

    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will helps you to pass the json object data to the activity function:

**Activity function:**

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    req_body = req.get_json()
    return func.HttpResponse(f"description is {req_body.get('description')}")
```